# extracting parameter values from one large string

Tags: python, string, matlab, text, cell

I have the following string (loaded from a .txt file to a Matlab cell):

```
text = 'u1 @ t=0, K=3.1416, gamma=0.1, A=-0.1 u1 @ t=0.01, K=3.1416, 
gamma=0.1, A=-0.1 u1 @ t=0.02, K=3.1416, gamma=0.1, A=-0.1 u1 @ t=0.03, 
K=3.1416, gamma=0.1, A=-0.1'
```

The whole string variable is very long (from t=0 to t=1 and for different parameter values). I want to separate them into multiple cells so that

- `A(1)='u1 @ t=0, K=3.1416, gamma=0.1, A=-0.1'`,
- `A(2)='u1 @ t=0.01, K=3.1416, gamma=0.1, A=-0.1'`,
- etc.

  Or even better is to extract the variables of the parameters `t`, `K`, `gamma`, `A` and store them in an array.

How to do this in Matlab? (or in Python)

Edit:

Turns out the first few entry in my data is in the form `... t=1E-4, ... t=2E-4, ...... t=9E-4, ... t=0.001`, and some of the answers will skip the first few time steps which are in scientific notations. How to handle those numbers as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex.

A simple regex to get numbers is this: `'-?\d*\.?\d*'`.

To get your data, you can use this regex.

```
'u1 @ t={0}, K={0}, gamma={0}, A={0}'.format('-?\d*\.?\d*')
```

Example:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = 'u1 @ t=0, K=3.1416, gamma=0.1, A=-0.1 u1 @ t=0.01, K=3.1416, gamma=0.1, A=-0.1 u1 @ t=0.02, K=3.1416, gamma=0.1, A=-0.1 u1 @ t=0.03, K=3.1416, gamma=0.1, A=-0.1'
>>> r = '-?\d*\.?\d*'
>>> re.findall('u1 @ t={0}, K={0}, gamma={0}, A={0}'.format(r), text)
['u1 @ t=0, K=3.1416, gamma=0.1, A=-0.1', 'u1 @ t=0.01, K=3.1416, gamma=0.1, A=-0.1', 'u1 @ t=0.02, K=3.1416, gamma=0.1, A=-0.1', 'u1 @ t=0.03, K=3.1416, gamma=0.1, A=-0.1']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split your text with [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-contents). For instance, you can split on each space which is followed by “u1”:

```py
import re
from pprint import pprint

text = 'u1 @ t=0, K=3.1416, gamma=0.1, A=-0.1 u1 @ t=0.01, K=3.1416, gamma=0.1, A=-0.1 u1 @ t=0.02, K=3.1416, gamma=0.1, A=-0.1 u1 @ t=0.03, K=3.1416, gamma=0.1, A=-0.1'

lines = re.split(r'\s+(?=u1)', text)
pprint(lines)
```

You get:

```py
['u1 @ t=0, K=3.1416, gamma=0.1, A=-0.1',
 'u1 @ t=0.01, K=3.1416, gamma=0.1, A=-0.1',
 'u1 @ t=0.02, K=3.1416, gamma=0.1, A=-0.1',
 'u1 @ t=0.03, K=3.1416, gamma=0.1, A=-0.1']
```

You can then parse each line of this result to extract the attributes:

```py
for line in lines:
    attrs = {}
    for value in line[5:].split(", "):
        k, v = value.split("=")
        attrs[k] = float(v)
    print(attrs)
```

You get;

```py
{'t': 0.0, 'K': 3.1416, 'gamma': 0.1, 'A': -0.1}
{'t': 0.01, 'K': 3.1416, 'gamma': 0.1, 'A': -0.1}
{'t': 0.02, 'K': 3.1416, 'gamma': 0.1, 'A': -0.1}
{'t': 0.03, 'K': 3.1416, 'gamma': 0.1, 'A': -0.1}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without `regex`, the variables are stored as floats in 2D array:

```
s = '''u1 @ t=0, K=3.1416, gamma=0.1, A=-0.1 u1 @ t=0.01, K=3.1416, gamma=0.1, A=-0.1 u1 @ t=0.02, K=3.1416, gamma=0.1, A=-0.1 u1 @ t=0.03, K=3.1416, gamma=0.1, A=-0.1'''

out = []
for i in s.split('u1 @'):
    if not i.strip():
        continue
    out += [[float(v.split('=')[-1]) for v in i.split(',')]]

from pprint import pprint
pprint(out)
```

Prints:

```
[[0.0, 3.1416, 0.1, -0.1],
 [0.01, 3.1416, 0.1, -0.1],
 [0.02, 3.1416, 0.1, -0.1],
 [0.03, 3.1416, 0.1, -0.1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def to_cells(string):
strings = list(filter(None, string.split('u1 @ ')))
cells = {}

for cell in strings:
    pairs = cell.split(',')
    for pair in pairs:
        k, v = pair.split('=')
        k = k.strip()
        v = float(v)
        if k in cells:
            cells[k].append(v)
        else:
            cells[k] = [v]

return cells
```

You can use the function like this:

```
res = to_cells(
    'u1 @ t=0, K=3.1416, gamma=0.1, A=-0.1 u1 @ t=0.01, K=3.1416, gamma=0.1, A=-0.1 u1 @ t=0.02, K=3.1416,'
    ' gamma=0.1, A=-0.1 u1 @ t=0.03, K=3.1416, gamma=0.1, A=-0.1'
)

for x in res:
    print(x, '\t====>\t', res[x])
```

And the output will look like:

```
t   ====>    [0.0, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03]
K   ====>    [3.1416, 3.1416, 3.1416, 3.1416]
gamma   ====>    [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]
A   ====>    [-0.1, -0.1, -0.1, -0.1]
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You've gotten a lot of Python answers, so here's a MATLAB one. You can use the function [`regexp`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) to parse the string, then [`vertcat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vertcat.html), [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html), and [`str2double`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html) to reshape and convert the resulting cell array of strings into an N-by-4 matrix of values. Starting with this sample data (4 sets of entries in one string):

```
str = 'u1 @ t=0, K=3.1416, gamma=0.1, A=-0.1 u1 @ t=0.01, K=3.1416, gamma=0.1, A=-0.1 u1 @ t=0.02, K=3.1416, gamma=0.1, A=-0.1 u1 @ t=0.03, K=3.1416, gamma=0.1, A=-0.1';
```

The code is just 2 lines:

```
vals = regexp(str, 'u1 @ t=([-\.\dE]+), K=([-\.\dE]+), gamma=([-\.\dE]+), A=([-\.\dE]+)', 'tokens');
vals = cellfun(@str2double, vertcat(vals{:}));
```

And the result:

```
vals =

                   0   3.141600000000000   0.100000000000000  -0.100000000000000
   0.010000000000000   3.141600000000000   0.100000000000000  -0.100000000000000
   0.020000000000000   3.141600000000000   0.100000000000000  -0.100000000000000
   0.030000000000000   3.141600000000000   0.100000000000000  -0.100000000000000
```

Each column contains the values for `t`, `K`, `gamma`, and `A`.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about strings vs characters vs cells in Matlab. I got an error `Brace indexing is not supported for variables of this type.` in the last line. What's the expected data type of the variables `str` and `vals` in the above codes?

Comment: @Physicist: I assumed `str` was type `char` (i.e. a vector of characters), like in your examples. Then the output from `regexp` should be a cell array of cell arrays of character vectors.

Comment: if the first few `t` values are in scientific notation, e.g. `t=0 ... t=1E-4 ... t=2E-4 ...... t=9E-4 ... t=0.001 ... t=0.002 ...`, how should I modify the regular expressions for `t=(...)`?

Comment: @Physicist: I updated the regex pattern, so it should be able to handle scientific notation now.

Answer (score 0):

Another Matlab, regex-based solution. Denoting the string (character vector) by `s`,

```
v = reshape(str2double(regexp([s ' '], '(?<=(t|K|gamma|A)=).+?(?=,| )', 'match')), 4, []).';
```

gives, in your example,

```
v =
                   0   3.141600000000000   0.100000000000000  -0.100000000000000
   0.010000000000000   3.141600000000000   0.100000000000000  -0.100000000000000
   0.020000000000000   3.141600000000000   0.100000000000000  -0.100000000000000
   0.030000000000000   3.141600000000000   0.100000000000000  -0.100000000000000
```

The regular expression matches whatever is preceded by `t=`, `K=` etc and followed by either a comma or a space. A space is added at the end of the string so that the last match can be found. `str2double` converts the matched substring to a number (if possible). Then some transposing and reshaping is used to arrange the results as a matrix, where each of the 4 variables is a column.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rudimentary way to do this in MATLAB:

```
text ='u1 @ t=0, K=3.1416, gamma=0.1, A=-0.1 u1 @ t=0.01, K=3.1416, gamma=0.1, A=-0.1 u1 @ t=0.02, K=3.1416, gamma=0.1, A=-0.1 u1 @ t=0.03, K=3.1416, gamma=0.1, A=-0.1';
a=size(text);
pos1=strfind(text, 'u1'); % first position of variable
pos2=strfind(text, 'A='); % position of 'A='
pos2=pos2+5; % since after 'A=' there are five spaces until the end of the desired variable
vars=length(char); % number of new variables within 'text'
for i=1:length(pos2)
     output{i}=text(pos1(i):pos2(i)); % output variable as cell with entries as new variables
end
```

It finds the position of the first and last characters of the desired variable and removes these from 'text'. I would recommend following a similar method to extract the text for individual variable names and values. I would use the "strfind" function on the '=' sign for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done more easily without regexp in MATLAB. Using string instead of char also helps.

```
result = extractAfter(text,'u1 @ ');
result = split(result, 'u1 @ ');
result = split(result, ',');
result = extractAfter(result,'=');
result = double(result);
```

This is probably the fastest solution so far.

```
>> testFunc
Elapsed time is 0.075453 seconds. % My solution
Elapsed time is 2.820094 seconds. % Luis Mendo solution

function testFunc()

    text = "u1 @ t=0, K=3.1416, gamma=0.1, A=-0.1 u1 @ t=0.01, K=3.1416, " + ...
           "gamma=0.1, A=-0.1 u1 @ t=0.02, K=3.1416, gamma=0.1, A=-0.1 u1 @ t=0.03, " + ...
           "K=3.1416, gamma=0.1, A=-0.1";

    % My solution
    tic
    for i = 1:1e4
        result = extractAfter(text,'u1 @ ');
        result = split(result, 'u1 @ ');
        result = split(result, ',');
        result = extractAfter(result,'=');
        result = double(result);
    end
    toc

    % Luis Mendo solution
    tic;
    for i = 1:1e4
        result = reshape(str2double(regexp(text + ' ', '(?<=(t|K|gamma|A)=).+?(?=,| )', 'match')), 4, [])';
    end
    toc
```